# How to implement conditional PHP in Footer

Tags: php, theme-development, footer

Hoping for a little bit of help...I have added a script in **footer.php** and I want the script to run on all pages but not on "contact" page.  What would be the coding/conditional to do this? Thank you.

Comment: By *script* you mean Javascript or PHP? Can you please post your current relevant code?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response birgire  I have figured it out.  I am new here and not sure how to post what I used

<?php if (is_page('contact') ) { ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please add that to your answer.

Comment: Thank you!  And yep done..was figuring out how to do.  Have a great day!

Comment: Note that you can accept your own answer (if you're registered), to close the question. But to help others as well, we should avoid pure code dumps and also add some explanation too, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, thanks :)

```
<?php if (is_page('contact') ) { ?>
<?php } else { ?>
placed script here
<?php } ?>
```